# Is a WiFi dongle compatible with any country?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am planning to buy the Alfa AWUS036H Wi-Fi USB Adapter which is only sold in the united state . I live in Australia and I was wondering would this wifi adapter be compatible in Australia? Is there any criteria I should look out ? like maybe united state uses a different wifi frequency then australia?

[http://www.amazon.com/Alfa-AWUS036H-Wireless-Long-Rang-Panel/dp/B003YI4HRM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YI4HRM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the drivers and how the OS handles it. Apple for example uses wifi devices that can access all 802.11b/g/n channels, but limits it to US channels when in the US, UK channels in the UK, Japanese Channels in Japan. I Cannot access channel 14 when my location is set to US, as the US does not allow channel 14. It physically **can** work, but won't due to a user selectable setting.

Your device should be fine though. Windows doesn't discriminate like OS X does. Apple goes beyond the necessary all the time. If anything, the device will not accept, connect to, or show the channels beyond the default US ones, which may be inconvenient if you move around a lot, but easily fixed on a home router.

I will update on the Australia vs US differences later, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi#Wi-Fi_radio_spectrum), some countries allow more bands than the USA's 1 - 11. Australia, specifically, adds two more channels. So if you use a US-licensed WiFi device, you may not be able to connect to a few networks in Australia.

Comment: Was about to post the same, from a practical point of view not many people use those extra channels and I have that exact model and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that wifi is wifi, and the signal for that should remain the same no matter where you are. So, yes, I think you can use a wifi dongle in any country. I think that's what you were asking anyways.

Comment: thinking and knowing are completely different.  hes looking for answers, not guesses